# No exact matches in call to instance method 'append' : Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase

so I am trying to get values from firebase into a table. therefore first I am adding the data items to a list of type[Dictonary]

the data is like this:

```
Posts:
    P1 :
        post data....
    P2:
        post data....
```

---

code I'm using

```swift
let Posts: [Dictionary<String,Any>]! = nil
var dict = Postsnapshot?.value as? Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
Posts.append(contentsOf: dict.values)
```

I am doing something like this but it throws me this error "No exact matches in call to instance method 'append' ". I have tried every initializer even list.append(Dict) , still the same error. what should I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling your array `Posts` with a capital letter and you probably have a type declared somewhere with the sam exact name and the compiler is confused. Of course you also need to make the `posts` a `var` to be able to add something to is since `let` makes it immutable.

A much cleaner and correct way to write this code would be this:

```swift
var posts: [Dictionary<String,Any>] = []
let dict = postsnapshot?.value as? Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>
posts.append(contentsOf: Array(dict?.values ?? []))
```

Also please rename the `Postsnapshot` property to `postsnapshot` unless you are actually calling a static property on a `Postsnapshot` type.

Here are some resources for learning how to style your Swift code:

- [The Official raywenderlich.com Swift Style Guide.](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide)
- [Swift Style Guide by Google](https://google.github.io/swift/)

But to learn more on how to use Swift most efficiently I would **strongly** suggest to take a look a the official [Swift Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) and preferably reading the whole thing. It's incredibly informative!

Comment: does declaring variables with capital letters cause problems or it's somehow different? i mean what's the issue it's just a variable?

Comment: btw thanks. there were other problems also your post helped me with them.

Comment: I will not should cause problems by itself but it is super confusing for people reading you code since the standard (not official but obeyed by everyone) way to name properties is to use a [Camel Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) with a first letter being lowercased. You only start with Uppercased letter when naming types such as classes, structs, actors and protocols.

Comment: @ManuBalyan Happy to help, I would appreciate the accept and upvote if this helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Using loop append one by one value in array

eg.

var Posts: [Dictionary<String,Any>]! = nil

var dict = Postsnapshot?.value as? Dictionary<String, Dictionary<String, Any>>

for val in dict.values {

```
Posts.append(val)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this answer in case anyone like me faces this issue when the problem isn't really with the `append` method itself but with what was passed to the `append` method.

In my case, I tried to append a newly created instance of a struct to a an array of the said struct. One of the parameters I was supposed to supply to the struct's initializer was a string. I incidentally passed in an enum instead of the enum's `rawValue`. Since I was creating the object and initializing the struct in the same line, Xcode showed me the error mentioned in the question for some reason.

```
private var items: [Item] = []

func addItem(name: String, currency: Currency){ 
  items.append(
    Item(
      name: name, 
      currency: currency
    )
  )
}
```

The parameter was currency.

I had to seperate the struct's initialization from it's addition to the array by assigning to a variable first then appending that variable to the array before I got the right error message. After I resolved the issue I made it a one-liner again.

```
let item = Item(
    name: name, 
    currency: currency
  )
items.append(item)
```